# Getting started with SSO/SAML/OWIN

Tags: saml, onelogin

I need to setup a custom Identity Provider using SAML 2.0. Problem is I don't really know where to start. I want to ultimately integrate this into an existing .NET 4 project, but in the mean time I've been trying to get this setup in a new, empty project.

And when I say "start" I mean from the very beginning. It seems that you have to have something with OWIN setup, but that may just be something else. I've looked at Sustainsys and OneLogin and they seem to base their examples on knowing a lot more than I do.

FWIW, we're trying to integrate with Brightcove as they offer SSO via SAML. They state that they work with OneLogin and others. They provide some fields and information such as:

- Endpoint - I know what this is.
- X.509 cert - I know what it is and I think I've created one on the Onelogin site. I've pasted it into Brightcove. Not sure what I need to do locally. I have the private key, X.509, and CSR.
- SAML Issuer/Entity ID Override - Says it's provided by the SSO provider, which is me, which I don't know. This is what Brightcove says:

  > By default Gallery uses the ID of your access control profile, but you can override it here.
- ACS URL Override - I think I understand this. After a validate the login this is where I send them back.
- SAML AuthnContext Override - Has a default value: `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:AC:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport` Not sure if I need to match this somewhere or if I should override it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A SAML IdP needs to support multiple SAML profiles. It's a lot of work. Can you install the Internet2 IdP and use that? https://www.shibboleth.net/products/identity-provider/

Comment: I only need to support Brightcove's SAML profile for now and I'm up against a deadline. I just downloaded the Identity Provider .zip file from Shibboleth and looked around. Honestly I have no idea what this is. Like I said, I very unfamiliar with SAML and SSO in general outside the concepts.